# aiogram не находит модули aiogram.client и executor

Tags: python, aiogram, pip

```
    File "/home/ssoel/bot/hhh/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from aiogram.client.session.aiohttp import AiohttpSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram.client'
```

Тут версия - 2.25.2

Для теста использовал pythonanywhere, установил всё и т.д. Установил aiogram с executor вылазит ошибка та которая сверху.

```
      File "/home/ssoel/bot/hhh/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (/home/ssoel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/__init__.py)
```

А тут версия - 3.0.0b7

а когда установил aiogram с aiogram.client выходит ошибка та, которая сверху

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности, «пробема с тем-то» - это плохой заголовок.

Comment: Одновременно они у тебя не будут работать. aiogram.client.session.aiohttp есть в aiogram 3, но нет в aiogram 2. С executor наоборот: он есть во второй версии, но нет в третьей

Answer (score 0):

Одновременное использование этих модулей невозможно.

`aiogram.client` - есть в третьей версии aiogram, но отсутствует во второй.

`executor` - напротив, есть во второй версии, но удален в v3.

Единственно верное решение - приступить к рефакторингу имеющегося кода с использованием модулей какой-то одной конкретной версии.

Comment: 13:29 ~/bot/hhh (master)$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ssoel/bot/hhh/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (/home/ssoel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/__init__.py)
13:29 ~/bot/hhh (master)$

Comment: теперь та же ошибка

Comment: не работает, такая же ошибка как с executor

Comment: @newgen1 Глянул в документацию, обновил ответ.